# Date - formatting for a database?

Tags: php

My HTML:

```
...value="{{ date("d/m/Y") }}">
```

My PHP:

```
$input['date'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($input['date']));
```

I need to format the date for my database, but the above code always produces:

```
string(19) "1970/01/01 00:00:00"
```

How can I get it to work, it appears to work when I change the slashes to dashes in the HTML, but I want the date formatted with slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date format is ambiguous. `d/m/Y` can be easily confused with `m/d/Y`. (Is `01/12/2014` Jan 12th or Dec 1st?). You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to resolve this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $input['date']);
$input['date'] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: I don't think that format is weird. It's the main format in Europe.

Comment: I didn't say weird. I said ambiguous.